# why does delete trigger an error when use in "delete shared_ptr::get()"

Tags: c++11

Suppose I have the following code:

```
#include <memory>
struct Foo{};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> pf = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    delete pf.get();
    //do anything else
    return 0;
}
```

Why can't I use `delete` directly delete the `Foo` object？
In my opinion, the problem is that after the smart pointer destructs, the `delete` will be called twice and leads to the undefined behavior.But why it triggers an error when I use the first time manually.
I am confused, please help me.

And I found that the return of `get()` in visual studio is equal to the allocation address for the real object `Foo` from `new`.Like following：

```
template<class... _Types>
        explicit _Ref_count_obj(_Types&&... _Args)
        : _Ref_count_base()
        {   // construct from argument list
        ::new (static_cast<void *>(&_Storage)) _Ty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...);
        }
```

Comment: You can only use `delete` on a pointer you got from `new`. `make_shared` is not `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct explanation is that you didn't get the pointer via `new`, therefore calling `delete` on it is undefined behavior, and the compiler can do whatever it wants.

You should not even think beyond that.

The implementation detail answer (subject to change without notice, results may differ between compiler versions or even compilation switches) is that `make_shared` allocates the reference counting control block and the object in a single allocation, and then gives you a pointer into this allocation. Since the control block will typically be allocated *before* the object, that means that the memory address you hand to `delete` is not the one returned from the memory allocator.

Comment: I found that the return of `get()` in visual studio is equal to the allocation address for the real object `Foo` from `new` in `make_shared`.

Comment: the call to `new` you're referencing is "placement new" and does not do allocation

Comment: Clarified. Hopefully.

Comment: @kmdreko I got it,actually I should `delete` the reference count control block.

Comment: @DickHunter You shouldn't delete anything. You should let `shared_ptr` do its thing.

Comment: @SebastianRedl yeah I know. I mean I understand the reason why it raise an error.Thanks.